# How do I concatenate individual columns from many pandas dataframes to a pre-existing pandas dataframe with a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble running a for loop with that will concatenate the "time" columns from a pandas dataframes into a preexisting dataframe.

The dataframes look something like:

west / east / long / lat / time/ geometry

My code looks like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filepath\.csv') # preexisting dataframe that are similar to the rest

for files in glob.iglob(r'filepath\*.csv'):
    dfs = pd.read_csv(files) 
    dfs_new = dfs.iloc[:,[4]] # choose the time column to add in to df
concat_data = pd.concat([df, dfs_new], axis = 1)
concat_data.to_csv('master.csv')
```

But, this only concatenates one file from the specified directory to the pre-existing dataframe (df) instead of all of them, like:

west / east / long / lat / time/ geometry/ time2

...how do I fix this to get all the files in the directory to contribute their "time" column to the pre-existing dataframe?

Comment: You will have to do the joining inside the loop, otherwise `dfs_new` will just contain a column from your last csv file.

Comment: @Wouter even when I bring `concat_data` into the for loop to concatenate, it still gives me the same result of just joining one csv's time column to `df` instead of all of the .csvs in the directory.